# SQL Server 2014 Full Backup and Restore to Another DB not restoring the full dataset

Tags: sql-server, database

Very hard to put a title for my issue.

Basically i have a production database on a hosted server.  And i have a daily process that backs up the database, then i use ftp to pull the bak file to the internal server and then i restore the database. When i restored todays backup with no errors, the transactions (in the main transaction table) from today weren't there.  only 62,253 rows

So i created a test database on the internal server and restored the backup to there.  And the transactions were there.  61,286 rows.

So the backup is fine... its just the restore isn't quite working correctly.  Here is the message i get from the faulty restore.

Have changed database name to XX

Processes
Restore XX
5 percent processed.
10 percent processed.
15 percent processed.
20 percent processed.
25 percent processed.
30 percent processed.
35 percent processed.
40 percent processed.
45 percent processed.
50 percent processed.
55 percent processed.
60 percent processed.
65 percent processed.
70 percent processed.
75 percent processed.
80 percent processed.
85 percent processed.
90 percent processed.
95 percent processed.
100 percent processed.
Processed 21352 pages for database 'XX', file 'xy_1_data' on file 16.
Processed 13696 pages for database 'XX', file 'xx' on file 16.
Processed 2 pages for database 'XX', file 'xy_1_log' on file 16.
RESTORE DATABASE successfully processed 35050 pages in 1.319 seconds (207.602 MB/sec).

So it looks like its worked properly... here is my restore script

```
    ALTER DATABASE [XX] SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;

    ALTER DATABASE [XX] SET OFFLINE;

    RESTORE DATABASE [XX] FROM  DISK = N'D:\SQLBAK\XX.bak' WITH  FILE = 16,  MOVE N'xy_1_data' TO N'D:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\xx_data.mdf',  MOVE N'xx' TO N'D:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\xx_data2.mdf',  MOVE N'xy_log' TO N'D:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\xx_log.ldf',  NOUNLOAD,  REPLACE,  STATS = 5

    ALTER DATABASE [XX] SET ONLINE;

    ALTER DATABASE [XX] SET MULTI_USER;

    ALTER DATABASE [XX] SET RECOVERY SIMPLE
```

So not sure what the solutions here is.

Should i go to incremental backup and restores?  Or is there an option i can use to ensure the full restore occurs... i am already using REPLACE.

Should i drop and recreate the database daily... as it did the full restore correctly on a brand new database

thanks in advance

Comment: OK Just worked it out.  Because its a backup set.  I actually need to increment the file number.  RESTORE DATABASE [XX] FROM  DISK = N'D:\SQLBAK\XX.bak' WITH  FILE = 16.  Today i need to use FILE = 19.

Comment: so now i need to work out the latest file number that exists in the bak file